# App rejection with auto-renewable purchase - Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

One of our application is continuously rejected after implementing auto-renewable subscription with below reason. Although we have followed guidelines to implement the screen.

We have also referred posts [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554187/how-to-program-auto-renewing-in-app-purchase-to-satisfy-apple-guidelines)

> Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions
>
> We noticed that your app or its metadata did not fully meet the terms
>   and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in
>   Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> Your app's binary did not include:
>
> – The following information about the auto-renewable nature of the
>   subscription • Title of publication or service • Length of
>   subscription (time period and content or services provided during each
>   subscription period) • Price of subscription, and price per unit if
>   appropriate • Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at
>   confirmation of purchase • Subscription automatically renews unless
>   auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the
>   current period • Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours
>   prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the
>   renewal • Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal
>   may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after
>   purchase • Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will
>   be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that
>   publication, where applicable – A link to the terms of use – A link to
>   the privacy policy
>
> Adding the above information to the StoreKit modal alert is not
>   sufficient; the information must also be displayed within the app
>   itself, and it must be displayed clearly and conspicuously during the
>   purchase flow without requiring additional action from the user, such
>   as opening a link.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app or its metadata to
>   include the missing information.

Attached screenshots for your reference.

[image]

Also, we show the whole set of plans in more option in the top right corner. what else is expected from apple?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: file an appeal with review board

Comment: Previously with the same reason app was rejected. When appealing the have approved the app. Why does this continues to happen?

Comment: its mystery!. we experienced same...

Comment: What was the fix ? @AmodGokhale

Comment: PLEASE ADD ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION, IF YOU FOUND ANY..

Comment: @Vats check my answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are able to fix this issue by adding these pieces of information on the landing page itself.   [image]

Comment: Great, I never thought I literally needed to add those. Do I need to add them on the App's Info too?

Comment: Only after this my app got approved

Comment: Thank you! Mine just got approved too.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem they have is with the way you are presenting the information as they outlined in their response:

> Adding the above information to the StoreKit modal alert is not
>   sufficient; the information must also be displayed within the app
>   itself, and it must be displayed clearly and conspicuously during the
>   purchase flow without requiring additional action from the user, such
>   as opening a link.

So you should try to present the information in a way that isn't tied to the purchase flow, in addition to being displayed in the purchase flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through App Store Review when you add a link to the **privacy policy** and **terms of use** from within the app and the app store description.

**Also you must put the note about auto-renewable subscription on your paywall OR app store description.**

For a detailed guide, check out: https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/apple-will-reject-your-subscription-app-if-you-dont-include-this-disclosure